# How to split long attributes on multiple lines using prettier?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, prettier, prettier-eslint

I used `vue`, `eslint` and `prettier`, and for longer html `class="..."` attributes `prettier` was splitting it into several lines:

[image: split class]

Now `prettier` just puts it in a single line and does not split long classes anymore:

[image: single line class]

It's not efficient when working with `tailwindcss`. Is this feature fully removed from prettier?

My `prettierrc` file:

```
{
    "printWidth": 80,
    "semi": false,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "es5",
    "useTabs": true,
    "tabWidth": 2
}
```